Regge Theory interpretation
I have a question on the physical interpretation of the Regge limit,
$$s\gg4m^2\gg|t|$$
where we are in the s-channel physical region and s and t the Mandelstam invariants. Usually, the $s$ is taken to infinity (as in ref. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.05177) and I don't get how it is possible to have the limit $s \rightarrow \infty$ since the scattering angle,
$$\cos\theta_t=1+\frac{2s}{t-4m^2}\tag{63}$$ will go to $\infty$ as well leaving us with a complex angle that I don't know how to interpret physically.

I think you have $t$ and $s$ mixed up. For s-channel elastic scattering of two equal mass particles
$$
\cos \theta =1+\frac{t}{2|{\bf P}|^2}= 1+\frac{t}{s-4m^2} 
$$
with $0>t> - 4|{\bf P}|^2$.
No scattering is $t=0$. See here
